# SQLAlchemy error when upgrading Apache Superset

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation

I don't know if this is the right place to post this but I'm desperate. I've been following instructions on how to install Apache Superset based on this link:

https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-from-scratch

I was able to complete the following tasks:

i) install all required dependencies;
ii) install and start python virtual environment.

However, when running the command "superset db upgrade", I get the following error:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: filter_type
> [SQL: ALTER TABLE row_level_security_filters ADD COLUMN filter_type varchar(255)]

[image]

I have no idea on how to start debugging this. My system info is below:

- Ubuntu 18.04;
- Apache Superset 0.38.1
- SQLAlchemy 1.3.24

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check that first error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has been resolved. Steps I took to solve it:

1. Remove all Apache Superset dependencies;
2. Upgrade Ubuntu to 20.04;
3. Install dependencies packages recommended on superset documentation (I did not use python virtual environment);
4. Run superset installation (you might have to downgrade some packages).

it seems that Ubuntu 18.04 was not compatible with latest version of Apache Superset and its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Surely TABLE `row_level_security_filters` already has a COLUMN `filter_type`; and you can't have two columns with the same name?

Comment: Look, I've not created this table and I have no idea where it is or the procedure to avoid this query from being executed. This is the output of the command "superset db upgrade", not a sql query into a sql management software, this should not be an issue as you're not supposed to be correcting an automatic procedure during installation phase. I've triple checked all documentation regarding Apache Superset. It makes no sense.